# Postgres installation on Docker Ruby Alpine

Tags: ruby, postgresql, docker, alpine-linux

I'm trying to complete the setup for my Rails application, using Docker. For development I use `docker-compose.yml`, and for production just the `Dockerfile`, as I want to deploy using Dokku (which has no support for compose).

**In development everything is running fine, I'm getting my containers (app, webpacker and postgres), but in production mode my postgres container is missing... and also Dokku can't deploy correctly. I tried many ways, but nothing seems to work :(**

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ruby:2.5.5-alpine

ARG PRECOMPILEASSETS

ENV NODE_OPTIONS "--max_old_space_size=4096"
ENV SECRET_KEY_BASE=foo

RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
    build-base \
    git \
    postgresql-dev \
    postgresql-client \
    imagemagick \
    nodejs-current \
    yarn \
    python2 \
    tzdata \
    file

RUN gem install bundler
# Install gems
RUN mkdir /gems
WORKDIR /gems
COPY Gemfile .
COPY Gemfile.lock .
RUN bundle install -j4 --retry 3 \
    # Remove unneeded files (cached *.gem, *.o, *.c)
    && rm -rf /usr/local/bundle/cache/*.gem \
    && find /usr/local/bundle/gems/ -name "*.c" -delete \
    && find /usr/local/bundle/gems/ -name "*.o" -delete

RUN yarn install

ARG INSTALL_PATH=/beweeg
ENV INSTALL_PATH $INSTALL_PATH
WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH
COPY . .

# Precompile assets (or not)
RUN docker/potential_asset_precompile.sh $PRECOMPILEASSETS

# Expose Puma port
EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["docker/startup.sh"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:11-alpine
    ports:
      - 5433:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres

  webpacker:
    image: beweeg_development
    command: bin/webpack-dev-server
    volumes:
      - .:/beweeg:cached
    ports:
      - 3035:3035

  app:
    image: beweeg_development
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - PRECOMPILEASSETS=NO
    links:
      - db
      - webpacker
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - .:/beweeg:cached
```

As you'll see using docker-compose makes no problem, but if I want to build and run as production (without compose), then I cannot get pg installed correctly.
Previously I was using a Ruby slim image, and then using the following command:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl gnupg
RUN echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ stretch-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
RUN curl -q https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add -
```

was working nicely... but in order to reduce my images sizes, I'd prefer to stay now with Alpine.

I'm quite a noob, so please forgive me if the answer seems obvious... And thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: If you’re at all looking at production-oriented deploys, remove the `volumes:` that mount your local source tree over the container: you will not separately copy your source code to the production systems and this can introduce significant differences.  `links:` has almost no effect in current Docker and you can also safely delete that.

Comment: This having been said: what problem are you actually encountering?

Comment: Are you trying to build postgres in the same container as your app? Its not a good idea. It should go on separate VPS. [`Just follow Dokku official way of app deployment`](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/deployment/application-deployment/#linking-backing-services-to-applications)

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough... I updated my question. In fact I'm trying to have a pg container built correctly, but as Dokku doesn't allow docker-compose files, I'd have to make this work, only using the Dockerfile (I guess). But can't figure out how to do this